# Nginx urls that maps to php files?

Tags: php, nginx, extension

I'm trying to configure my nginx server such that any php file will be accessible without giving it's extension.

I'm already aware of many similar questions/answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760883/nginx-setting-a-default-file-extension/7761779#7761779 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760883/nginx-setting-a-default-file-extension and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975218/remove-php-from-url-with-rewrite-rule but I want to go a bit further :

If the request contains the .php file, we will return a 404.

So for example say I have in my folder :

- index.php
- search.php
- history.php

I need to acces them using

- index.php => / OR /index
- search.php => /search
- history.php => /history

and if the user tries /search.php, he will get a 404 in returns.

The last part is the tricky one for me. Moreover, when I access files without the PHP extension, NGinx downloads the file for me, without compiling it (so I have access to the code source, containing database access :/)

How can I do ?

Here's my actual configuration :

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        root /srv/www/status/;

        index index.php;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/default-access_log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/default-error_log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri.php =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Don't design your web application like this. Use the [Front Controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) instead.

Comment: you wanna without .php and what i see in your nginx config?
fastcgi_index index.php;

Comment: @Ilja it has no relations. From the doc (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_index), it's just used as replacement for the "/" url. So it's better for me.